# Class inheritance in Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, inheritance

solved: restarting unity and visual studio solved the problem.

im trying to inherit a class called Enemy from another one called Frog.
In order to do that i use:

```
public class Frog : Enemy
```

When i do that, i get an error saying that the type or namespace Enemy could not be found.

Even tho it says that the class is not found, im still able to get all the information, for example i override the void Start and get all the information correctly using:

```
protected override void Start()
```

My problem is that, even tho i get over 20 error messages on the class Frog, when i try it in-game i dont get any compile errors and everything works exactly as intended.

Do i just leave the errors in the code because the script works as intended or am i missing something which may lead to a mess on the future?

Comment: Please provide more information like:
 Are you using Visual Studio? Post some more code (like the errors), and post you editor output log

Comment: Close down Visual Studio and Unity and open them up again. It might simply be a glitch of communication between the two.

Comment: Can you post the relevant parts of both classes? What is their namespace, how are the Start methods defined? Do you call `base` in `Frog`?

Comment: @aalmigthy yes i use `base.Start();` and then on the enemy class i just use `protected virtual void Start()`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try either or both of these:

1) Restart your code editor, if it doesn't help.

2) Delete the .sln, and .csproj files and then from unity click 'Assets' => 'Open C# Project', check if that helps.

Comment: the first one solved it, i restarted Unity and now i dont get any errors. Thanks